# Nicotine+ Problem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gtk

When I launch Nicotine Plus, I get the following message:

```
Gtk-Message: 21:10:30.657: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
lun 21:10 Disabled UPnP support due to errors: Failed to import miniupnpc
          module: No module named miniupnpc. Also: Failed to run upnpc binary:
          Problem while executing command ['upnpc'] (1 of 1)
lun 21:10 Note: Python Bindings for libsexy were not found. To enable spell
          checking, get them from http://www.chipx86.com/wiki/Libsexy or your
          distribution's package manager. Look for sexy-python or python-sexy.
```

I tried to connect to the telnet server with

```
telnet server.slsknet.org 2242
```

But I get this message:

> Connected to vps.slsknet.org.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> Connection closed by foreign host.

What can I do?

Comment: ... I figure out that I was banned for the servers of soulseek ...so using now my mobile connection I can download  from Nicotine plus...but is slow...so  I wanna use a proxy ....please ...how can I make a proxy in bionic for my nicotine ?

Answer (score 0):

Nicotine itself is installable by using commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nicotine
```

To fix warning about canberra use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Upnpc python module came from [`python-miniupnpc` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&searchon=names&keywords=miniupnpc), to install it use

```
sudo apt-get install python-miniupnpc
```

Nicotine package [depends](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nicotine) depends on `python-sexy` package which is not available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. This dependency is very outdated, last version was available in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. So you can ignore it without functionality loss.

---

Fresh idea - [Nicotine web-site](https://nicotine-plus.github.io/nicotine-plus//) lists PPA with stable version. You can install fresh Nicotine from it using commands below:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nicotine-team/stable
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6CEB6050A30E5769
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nicotine
```

You may want to check [screenshots](https://nicotine-plus.github.io/nicotine-plus/data/screenshots/SCREENSHOTS.html).

Comment: Many thanks N0rbert ...I followed your directions...but now ...when I launch Nicotine Plus a got a message:


 [Warn] UPnP exception: UPnP does not work on this network
[2021-06-29 11:07:47] [Warn] Failed to automate the creation of UPnP Port Mapping rule.


And in Nicotine tells: "Server appear down or  not responding"


In Nicotine I have checked the option "Use UPnP to automatically map the port on my router"    ,,,I have also the message "Your IP address has not retrieved from the server...",,,,    please help me ... many thanks in advance

Comment: Then it really depends on the network characteristics. I'm not sure that UPnP is essential for Nicotine operation.

Comment: the port I use is open... well... I uncheked the UPnP option...but also nicotine tells me the message "Your IP address has not retrieved from the server..."  ... and can't enter any info in the "search item" text box...

Comment: I have just discovered that https://nicotine-plus.github.io/nicotine-plus/ has a link to PPA with newer Nicotine version. You can try it instead.

Comment: Thanks ! ...yes ... now I made a clean installation ...now with the github version that you tell me... but again the same message in Nicotine :"Server appear down or not responding" ..  Nicotine trying to connect to server.slsknet.org:2242... but nothing ... ;(    ... in the router the UPnP option is ON ....when I check the UPnP option Nicotine tells me "failed to automate the creation of UPnP rule port mapping rule" ...also I checked the port status from Nicotine and the port are open...

Comment: Really I'm not sure how it works and how it should work. Maybe you have to check Nicotine's protocol specifics by reading some its docs.